# Only one thread ever acquiring semaphore

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I have a program in which multiple threads are in a loop where they acquire a binary semaphore and then increase a global counter.  However, by printing out the thread IDs, I notice that only one thread ever acquires the semaphore.  Here's my MRE:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 10
#define MAX_COUNTER 100

struct threadCtx {
    sem_t sem;
    unsigned int counter;
};

static void *
threadFunc(void *args)
{
    struct threadCtx *ctx = args;
    pthread_t self;
    bool done = false;

    self = pthread_self();

    while (!done) {
        sem_wait(&ctx->sem);

        if ( ctx->counter == MAX_COUNTER ) {
            done = true;
        }
        else {
            sleep(1);
            printf("Thread %u increasing the counter to %u\n", (unsigned int)self, ++ctx->counter);
        }

        sem_post(&ctx->sem);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    struct threadCtx ctx = {.counter = 0};

    sem_init(&sem.ctx, 0, 1);

    for (int k=0; k<NUM_THREADS; k++) {
        pthread_create(threads+k, NULL, threadFunc, &ctx);
    }

    for (int k=0; k<NUM_THREADS; k++) {
        pthread_join(threads[k], NULL);
    }

    sem_destroy(&ctx.sem);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Thread 1004766976 increasing the counter to 1
Thread 1004766976 increasing the counter to 2
Thread 1004766976 increasing the counter to 3
...
```

If I remove the call to `sleep`, the behavior is closer to what I would expect (i.e., the threads being woken up in a seemingly indeterminate manner).  Why would this be?

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee that the scheduling will be 'fair' in any 'round-robin' sense.  Also note that you call `sleep(1)` with the semaphore acquired which will block all other threads invoking `sem_wait`.

Comment: "will block all other threads invoking `sem_wait`"  - That's intentional.

Comment: OK, then I think it comes back to the 'fairness' issue.  Having posted the semaphore your `while` loop immediately calls `sem_wait`.  There's no guarantee a context switch will occur between those two events.

Comment: I get that there's no guarantee.  However, it seems strange that the context would **never** switch.

Comment: You could possibly 'encourage' a context switch by adding a call to `sleep` or `nanosleep` immediately after the call to `sem_post`.

Comment: Is it because, if the semaphore's internal counter is positive, there's no system call?

Comment: The biggest problem with the example code is more strategic than tactical: using threads is wasteful here because you get substantially no actual concurrency, whether the worker threads switch off or not.  And if you did have appreciable concurrency then that would also solve the problem of one thread monopolizing the semaphore, too.

Comment: I agree.  The example is just to demonstrate behavior.  It’s not meant as a worthwhile program.

Comment: @DanielWalker Most OSes will switch contexts when the thread that keeps getting the resource uses up its timeslice. Timeslices sizes are chosen for that exact purpose. If you never let that thread use up its timeslice, then the thread may keep getting the resource. But it's up to you to not write threads that do work that you don't want done.

Comment: Sure, @DanielWalker, but if the example program is not representative of a more interesting one then what's the point of the question?  And if your real program implements the same antipattern then it has the same strategic problem.

Comment: It demonstrates the behavior under question.  The behavior is what I'm trying to understand since it violated my then understanding of how semaphores work.  Is it not enough that I'm trying to learn more about how things work under the hood?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz 'Most OSes will switch contexts when the thread that keeps getting the resource uses up its timeslice....what timeslice?   Nowhere does the OP state that there are more ready threads than cores.

Comment: @MartinJames Typical modern operating systems assign a thread a timeslice that it gets to use up until it's pre-empted. This happens regardless of the number of ready threads or cores.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz preempted for what?  If there are enough cores to run all ready threads, then there is nothing to replace a preempted thread, so any 'time slice' is pointless. Unless there are other threads with blocking system calls that are timing out, (admittedly very likely in a typical system), the timer interrupt can left disabled.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not sure what point you're trying to make. If you imagine some scenario where a thread has an infinite timeslice, my answer and comments are still correct.

Comment: @DanielWalker You say it seems strange that the context would never switch. But why should it? The thread that keeps getting the semaphore can always make forward progress and never uses up its timeslice. What would ever block it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why would this be?

Context switches are expensive and your implementation is, wisely, minimizing them. Your threads are all fighting over the same resource, trying to schedule them closely will make performance much worse, probably for the entire system.

Since the thread that keeps getting the semaphore never uses up its timeslice, it will keep getting the resource. It is your responsibility to write code to do the work that you want done. It's the implementation's responsibility to execute your code as efficiently as it can, and that's what it's doing.

Most likely, what's going under the hood is this:

1. The thread that keeps getting the sempahore can always make forward progress except when it is sleeping. But when it is sleeping, no other thread that needs the sempahore can make forward progress.
2. The thread that keeps getting the semaphore never exhausts its timeslice because it sleeps before that happens.

So there is no reason for the implementation to ever block this thread other than when it is sleeping, meaning that no other thread can get the semaphore. If you don't want this thread to keep sleeping with the semaphore and blocking other threads, then write different code.

Comment: “It’s your responsibility to write code to do work that you don’t want done” sounds a bit odd… is there a typo in there?

Answer (score 3):

David Schwartz's answer explains what is happening at a low level. That is to say, he's looking at it from the perspective of an OS developer or a hardware designer. Nothing wrong with that, but let's look at your program from the perspective of a Software Architect:

You've got multiple threads all executing the same loop.  The loop locks the mutex,* it does some "work," and then it releases the mutex. OK, but what does it do next? Almost the *very next thing* that your loop does after releasing the mutex is it locks the mutex again.  Your loop spends practically 100% of its time doing "work" with the mutex locked.

So, what's the point of running that same loop in multiple threads when there's *never* any opportunity for two or more threads to work at the same time?

If you want to use threads to do a parallel computation, you need to find/invent safe ways for the threads to do most of their work with the mutex *unlocked.* They should only lock a mutex for just long enough to post a result or, to take another assignment.

Sometimes that means writing code that is less efficient than single threaded code would be. But suppose that program (A) has a single thread that makes almost 100% use of a CPU, while program (B) uses eight CPUs but only uses them with 50% efficiency. Which program is going to win?

---

* I know, your example uses a `sem_t` (semaphore) object. But "semaphore" is *what* you are using. "Mutex" is the *role* in which you are using it.

Comment: I understand all of that.  As I mentioned in the comments, this MRE is just that.  It's not an attempt to do anything useful or efficient with threads.

Comment: @DanielWalker, OK, I didn't read your comment-dialogue with John Bollinger. If it was just you reading this, I would delete my answer because it is not helpful to you. But like I said, your question (including the code example) is very similar to many other questions on this site from people who do _not_ "understand all that." I'm going to leave my answer here for the benefit other people who might be searching for the same idea, but who have less understanding of the problem than you have.

Comment: I upvoted this because good answer, but also it does not mention 'quantum', 'timeslice' or any other cargo-cult gunge.

Comment: @DanielWalker well, first, an OS does not need to enforce any kind of quota/sharing of CPU when the number of ready threads is not greater than the number of cores.  Second, the general, and unqualified, use of terms like 'quantum' and 'timeslice' reinforces the unfortunate misconception that the timer interrupt is the only one that causes a scheduling/dispatch run and that I/O completion and inter-thread signaling have no effect on the set of running threads until the next timer interrupt.  If there are no threads waiting for CPU, and no syscalls timing out, the timer can be disabled.